# Validation rule not firing if there are empty spaces in Long text area field

Tags: case, validation, validation-rule, long-text-area, isblank

I have a validation rule that should fire whenever there is a value on field 'A' and the 'description' field Long Text Area(32000)) of case object is left blank.

This rule fires for manual cases but when case is created via email to case and

1. if the description field is blank
2. User edits and saves the record
3. due to some blank space at the start of the description field, the rule does not fire. Seems like some empty space.

please help.

Validation rule...

```
(
    (TRIM(Description ) == '') 
    ||  LEN(TRIM(Description ))  = 0
)
&& NOT(ISBLANK(Text( A__c )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ISBLANK()` along with `TRIM()` function to check the empty spaces or blank.

```
(ISBLANK(Description) 
|| LEN(TRIM(Description)) =0 )  
&& NOT(ISBLANK(Text( A__c )))
```

Comment: That did not work for blank spaces at the beginning of the text.(eventhough description field is blank)

Comment: updated my answer which worked for me